# Excel: How can I Find & Replace parts of formulas in a selection?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I use something like the Find & Replace tool to do the following in Excel 2016:

- Make a selection of cells
- Open Find & Replace
- Search through all of the formulas in that selection
- Replace part of that formula with something else

Example:
My company uses an excel sheet (a rather complex/advanced one) to estimate prices for our projects. Here's a screenshot:

Quote Sheet:

[image]

So basically, in the TOTAL QTY box at the top of each sheet metal section, the formula is "=Q1*QTY". The only problem with this is that there are 10+ overall part sections, each with their own QTY (QTY, QTY2, QTY3, etc...).

When I copy/paste more sections, the new sections always reference to the QTY from the one I copied, and I have to manually go through and change every single formula to reference the new QTY.

How can I use the find/replace tool to do it faster?

Comment: What's the new QTY reference compared to the old? What have you tried? If you need VBA, have you made any attempts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My plan would be to remove all the "=" - replace with xyxy for example as this never appears... Then do a copy / paste for the new section. Then select that new section and edit / replace QTYx with QTYz as necessary, then replace the xyxy with "=". I find this works well with my large sheets and avoids all those recalculation pauses.

Comment: I've saved so many coworkers so many work hours with this kind of approach

Comment: I'm glad someone else uses it - I was worried about posting it, but there is sure to be another way - there almost always is in excel...